# javascript - how to get object from array, and use its methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have a problem using a class methods, after it was inserted into array. when i pull it back i can no longer use it methods.

- and i know javascript does not have class, when i say class i mean object -or js equal.

suppose i have the following:

```
// a simple atomic class

function raw_msg(msg) {
  this.msg = msg;

  this.print = function () {
    console.log(this.msg);
  }

}

 // and then i have this container for this "atomic" class
 // which accept array of unknown object (known to me though..) = in_buffer
 // i.e in_buffer is just an array of objects (one type of object)

function buffer(in_buffer) {

  this.trans_buffer = null;

  if (in_buffer!=null)
     this.set_buffer (in_buffer);

  this.set_buffer = function (buffer) {
    this.trans_buffer = [];
    var length = buffer.length,
      row, new_raw_msg;
    for(var x = 0; x < length; x++) {
      row = buffer[x];
      this.trans_buffer.push(new raw_msg(row));
    }
    console.log(this.trans_buffer);
  }

  this.use_some_raw_msg_method = function () {
    var firstrow = this.trans_buffer[0];
    firstrow.print(); // here is the problem!!!
    //this here where i need help as it yield the error:
    //Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'print' 
  }
}


// this is how i use it, this code sits in a diffrent yet another class...

// this here im just building fake array
var buffer_in = [];
for (var x=0;x<10;x++)
   buffer_in.push ("whatever" + x);

this.trans_buffer = new trans_helper(buffer_in);

this.trans_buffer.use_some_raw_msg_method (); // will yield the error as described
```

i hope this here, is clear, ask away if you need clarifications.

thanks for your help!

- note to future readers - there is no problem in retrieving an object and using its methods.

Comment: How are you using `buffer`? All I can see is two classes (they should be Uppercase, by the way).

Comment: i will update, few moments

Comment: What are you getting in the `firstrow` object? If this is all there is, set up a fiddle please

Comment: if `firstrow` does not have a `print` method, it probably isn't an instance of `raw_msg`

Comment: ok, just to be clear, theoutically this layout should work? i.e my usage is "normal"? again thanks for your help!

Comment: Your usage sample is incorrect. It will complain `Object #<Object> has no method 'push'` even before you call any of the class methods. Shall I assume `buffer_in = []`?

Comment: Also, it will complain `this.set_buffer` is not a function inside the constructor. Shall I assume it was actually defined before it's used?

Comment: yes pls assume  buffer_in = [], i just typed it here.

Comment: Would you please test your code samples if they act as expected before posting them? Especially in the original post, where you have all the time you need to craft a perfect question :-)

Comment: when i console.log first row, i can see its properties, but not its methods, im new to js, so im not even sure how to test it properly, again many thanks for your help!

Comment: yes you are correct jan Dvorak, i assumed it can be answered easily, i was just showing a point, shall i delete, and repost it, after chekc?

Comment: @yaron You can edit the question instead of deleting and reposting

Comment: @yaron no need to delete and repost, just check and update. Also, it seems that Revers has already answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had several problems with your code.

1. Associative array does not have `.push()` method so the following line failed:

   ```
   buffer_in.push ("whatever" + x);
   ```

   To fix this just declare plain array:

   ```
   var buffer_in = [];
   ```
2. You tried to create instance of function called *trans_helper* which does not exist. The name is *buffer* instead, so fix would be:

   ```
   var trans_buffer = new buffer(buffer_in);
   ```
3. Last but not least, you tried to call function in the "class" when it still did not exist yet. JavaScript does not "compile" functions in advance, when inside function it will go line by line. So in this line in your code:

   ```
   this.set_buffer (in_buffer);
   ```

   There was still no function called "set_buffer" in your class. To fix this, place the function declaration above, on top.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/5Usa8/).

Comment: yes point 3 is correct!!!!!! i just discoverd it myself, all other mistakes, are just "copying" and "making it simple" errors, i learned for next time, and thanks for your help!